# Why doesn't this select list render with the correct item selected based on the defaultValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `ReactJS` component:

```
var RegionsList = React.createClass({

    handleChange: function () {
        var regionId = this.refs.userRegions.getDOMNode().value;
        this.props.onRegionSelected(regionId);
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        $.get("/translation/activeuserregions", function(result) {
            if(this.isMounted()) {
                this.setState({
                    selectedRegionId: result.SelectedRegionId,
                    regions: result.Regions
                })
            }     
        }.bind(this));
    },

    getInitialState: function(props) {
        return {
            selectedRegionId: '',
            regions: []    
        }    
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div id="RegionsListForm" className="navbar-form navbar-left regions-list">
                <div className="input-group navbar-searchbox">
                    <span className="input-group-addon">
                        <span>Region</span>
                    </span>
                    <select ref="userRegions" onChange={this.handleChange} defaultValue={this.state.selectedRegionId} className="form-control valid" id="region" name="region" aria-invalid="false">
                        {this.state.regions.map(function(region) {
                            return <option key={region.Id} value={region.Id} label={region.RegionName}>{region.RegionName}</option>        
                        })}                                             
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },


})
```

It appears to work correctly. But initially it does not render with the correct item selected. Although the `defaultValue` appears to be set correctly so I don't understand why.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When the `<select>` is initially mounted, the default value is `''`. Once an uncontrolled form component is in the DOM, React doesn't look updates to the `defaultValue` prop. In this case it looks like your intention is to always have the `selectedRegionId` state match what's shown to the user, so you may want to change `defaultValue` to `value` and add a `this.setState({selectedRegionId: regionId});` call to your onChange handler; then your component state and the DOM will always be in sync.