# react-select wont display default value

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to display a default value in react-select based on an array of values. I have confirmed that the value is equal to the value I am comparing against. I have looked through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495696/how-to-set-a-default-value-in-react-select?rq=1), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460443/setting-a-default-value-with-react-select-not-working), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884294/why-doesnt-this-select-list-render-with-the-correct-item-selected-based-on-the), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51754700/react-select-not-recognizing-default-value), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52436805/react-how-to-set-default-value-in-react-select) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495696/how-to-set-a-default-value-in-react-select).  Despite the similarities, the `defaultValue` will still not set. I have confirmed by loggin the result of my comparators that they are the same, both in uppercase, both strings.

My Select element is

```
   <Select
    name="disposition"
    classNamePrefix="select"
    options={statusOptions}
    ref={selectInputRefPlan}
    styles={singleStylesRowComp}
    defaultValue={statusOptions.filter(
      ({ value }) => value.value === lead.disposition
    )}
  />
```

and my array is

```
 const statusOptions = [
    { value: "HOT", label: i18n._(t`HOT`) },
    { value: "WIP", label: i18n._(t`WIP`) },
    { value: "LOST", label: i18n._(t`LOST`) },
    { value: "DNC", label: i18n._(t`DNC`) },
    { value: "WON", label: i18n._(t`WON`) },
    { value: "NEW", label: i18n._(t`NEW`) },
  ];
```

I am testing against the `value` and not the `label`, so translation issues won't arise. when i log the response, `value.value === 'NEW'` and `lead.disposition === 'NEW'`, however, the `defaultValue` will not set. I have also tried the prop `value`, as well as having read through the 6 or 7 similar posts.  Is there a simple syntax error? or something else I am missing?

[Here is a sandbox link that demonstrates the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-wind-s3mtj?file=/index.js)

Comment: is there a chance that because the default value is only what it starts as, then it cannot be reassigned after mounting of the select?

Comment: I had a similar thought, but thats why i tried using the value prop as well... thoughts? im putting together a codesandbox right now

Comment: @AlexanderHemming there is now a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-wind-s3mtj?file=/index.js

Comment: would go with value prop for more controlled select components. All i can think of otherwise is how lead.disposition is made

Comment: Well the sandbox works as expected. What is the eror you are getting?

Comment: @Domino987the sandbox is not displaying the value given to the select. how is it working as expected? is there something im not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your filter function. You decompose value, and then access value.value. This is undefined.

Instead, take the option argument without decomposition, and access option.value.

```js
<Select
  name="disposition"
  classNamePrefix="select"
  options={statusOptions}
  ref={selectInputRefPlan}
  styles={singleStylesRowComp}
  defaultValue={statusOptions.filter((option) => option.value === lead.disposition)}
/>;
```